# Application failed to start when deploying to GKE, showing 'GcpContextAutoConfiguration' was excluded

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub, spring-cloud-gcp

I have an application, when I deployed to GCP, it failed to start but it was running all good in my local with docker. I have no idea how to resolve this, do I need to include anything in my properties file?

```html
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 1 of constructor in org.springframework.cloud.gcp.autoconfigure.pubsub.GcpPubSubAutoConfiguration required a bean of type 'org.springframework.cloud.gcp.core.GcpProjectIdProvider' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
    - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)

The following candidates were found but could not be injected:
    - Bean method 'gcpProjectIdProvider' in 'GcpContextAutoConfiguration' not loaded because auto-configuration 'GcpContextAutoConfiguration' was excluded
    - Bean method 'gcpProjectIdProvider' in 'GcpContextAutoConfiguration' not loaded because auto-configuration 'GcpContextAutoConfiguration' was excluded
    - Bean method 'gcpProjectIdProvider' in 'GcpContextAutoConfiguration' not loaded because auto-configuration 'GcpContextAutoConfiguration' was excluded


Action:

Consider revisiting the entries above or defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.cloud.gcp.core.GcpProjectIdProvider' in your configuration.
```

I've included the properties as below

```
spring.cloud.gcp.pubsub.enabled: true
spring.cloud.gcp.config.enabled: true
spring.cloud.gcp.security.iap.enabled: true
#I DO NOT have this line below
#spring.autoconfigure.exclude: org.springframework.cloud.gcp.autoconfigure.core.GcpContextAutoConfiguration
```

Inside my pom I've also included these

```
    <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-boot-release.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-cloud-gcp.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-pubsub</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-starter-pubsub</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-integration-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
<dependencies>
```

Anyone can help?

Answer (score 1):

The most likely reason for `GcpContextAutoConfiguration` to be excluded is that your deployed properties have `spring.cloud.gcp.core.enabled=false` somewhere.

To check exactly what Spring Boot autoconfigures and why, pass `-Ddebug=true` to your Java process (if running from Maven, pass it as `-Dspring-boot.run.jvmArguments="-Ddebug=true"`.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the Spring Cloud GCP starter to your dependencies that configures the authentication and project settings:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-starter</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Also, if you specify the `spring-cloud-gcp-starter-pubsub` dependency, it is not necessary to add the `spring-cloud-gcp-pubsub`, as it is already included in the first one.